# Activating Spring Profile active JVM arguments in GWT hosted mode

Tags: spring, gwt, maven, maven-3

I have a spring profile configuration as shown below

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="dfgdfg" />
        <property name="user" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/Test"/>
</beans>
```

I am trying to make one of this active via the VM argument `-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"` . This works in Tomcat and so does the `context-param` route in Hosted mode via the gwt-maven-plugin but I can't get the VM arguments to work . I tried `mvn -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" gwt:run` also tried to pass `-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"` via the VM arguments under the JRE tab in run configurations along with the goal `gwt:run` . I also tried the environment tab and even `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` but the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` doesn't budge . Is this because of the limited capability of the embedded server ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, simply gwt:maven plugin is kind of strange and it doesn't pass system properties to the launched JVM instance, and the only way to pass parameters is to put it into `<extraJvmArgs>` in plugin configuration e.g. in your case you have to add following to the configuration tag of gwt plugin:

`<extraJvmArgs>-Dspring.profiles.active=dev</extraJvmArgs>`

God knows why this works only this way, I wish there were some other normal way.

Comment: Problem resolved - Thanks . I was using extraJvmArgs for heap size but I missed this . Maven profile settings work with JVM arguments with GWT(-Denv="xyz") . Not this - weired .